# If $a^3=b^3$ then $a=b$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb R$ direct proof

Tags: calculus

While I was working through the first chapter of Spivak's Calculus, "Basic Properties of Numbers", where he introduces the Field Axioms and Order Axioms (P1 - P12), I thought about a problem which is not stated in the book, but could be formulated like this:

> Prove that if $a^3=b^3$ then $a=b$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb R$ using P1 - P12.

I worked out a proof by contraposition in the following way:

Suppose $a\neq b$.

1. $a<b$:

- Let $0<a$: **(i)** $(a<b \land 0<a)\implies a^2<ab$; $(a^2<ab \land 0<a)\implies a^3<a^2b$.  **(ii)** $(a<b \land 0<b)\implies ab<b^2$; $(ab<b^2 \land 0<b)\implies ab^2<b^3$. **(iii)**  $(ab<b^2 \land 0<a)\implies a^2b<ab^2$.

  It follows from (i), (ii) and (iii) that $a^3<b^3$.
- Let $a=0$: **(i)** with proof on pg. 7 (Spivak, Calculus, 3rd ed.; $a0=0$ ), $a^3=0$.  **(ii)** $(0<b \land 0<b)\implies 0<b^2$; $(0<b^2 \land 0<b)\implies 0<b^3$.

  It follows from (i) and (ii) that $a^3<b^3$.
- Let $a<0$ and $0<b$: **(i)** If $a<0$ then $0<a^2$, which is proven in the text of Chapter 1. $(0<a^2 \land 0>a)\implies a^3<0$, which is proven in a Poblem of Chapter 1. **(ii)** $0<b^3$ (see above).

  It follows from (i) and (ii) that $a^3<b^3$.
- Let $a<0$ and $0=b$:**(i)** $a^3<0$ (see above). **(ii)** with proof on pg. 7 (Spivak, Calculus, 3rd ed.; $a0=0$ ), $b^3=0$.

  It follows from (i) and (ii) that $a^3<b^3$.
- Let $b<0$:**(i)** $(a<b \land 0>a)\implies a^2>ab$; $(a^2>ab \land 0>a)\implies a^3<a^2b$.**(ii)** $(a<b \land 0>b)\implies ab>b^2$; $(ab>b^2 \land 0>b)\implies ab^2<b^3$.**(iii)**  $(ab>b^2 \land 0>a)\implies a^2b<ab^2$.

  It follows from (i), (ii) and (iii) that $a^3<b^3$.

2. $b<a$: Analogous to 1.

I fail to see how this can be shown with a direct proof. How would a direct proof of this problem look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a^{3}-b^{3} =(a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})$. So, it is enough to show that $a^{2}+ab+b^{2}>0$. For this we have $-ab \leq \frac {a^{2}+b^{2}} 2$ : This is just a restatement of $(a+b)^{2} \geq 0$. Hence $a^{2}+ab+b^{2} \geq \frac {a^{2}+b^{2}} 2 >0$ (except when $a=b=0$ but we already have $a=b$ in this case).

Comment: $a^2+ab+b^2=(a+b/2)^2+3b^2/4$.